# paragraph not showing numbering

Tags: paragraphs

I am using `\paragraph` in a command named `\kom`.  Looking at the documentation, `\paragraph{this}` should introduce a numbered paragraph, but it does not. What is the reason for this ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \kom {O{orange}om}
  {
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        { \paragraph{\color{#1}#3} }
      { \paragraph{\color[#1]{#2}#3} }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Something}  

\kom{Note} Here I describe rabbits.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another Ducky? What happened to the first one?

Comment: Try `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}`

Comment: `\paragraph` does not make a paragraph. It is a section heading (sub-subsubsection). Whether it gets a number or not depends on the class (and any packages).

Comment: Do you know why some people do not like using `\noindent`?  It is not used much in latex code.

Comment: A big point of LaTeX is to separate the content from the styling.  Whether to indent or not is a styling question that should be determined by the class and the context of the paragraph.  If you're using `\noindent` often, you should examine why that is and figure out a different way to approach things.  But what does that have to do with `\paragraph`?

Comment: I was using `\paragraph` to avoid using `\noindent`.  I am writing a title preceding a description, but that introduces line indentation.  But now, I do not want to call `\paragraph` as users might want it, which then could introduce numbering, which I do not want to have.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I thought you *wanted* it to introduce numbering. Why are you asking why it isn't producing a number if you don't want a number?

Comment: @Teepeemm That explains why it isn't good to use it in LaTeX documents, but it doesn't explain why it should be avoided in the code of packages/classes. Have I misunderstood your point?

Comment: @cfr Perhaps I misunderstood OP's "why some people do not like using `\noindent`".  I interpreted that to mean "what's wrong with ending every paragraph in my tex file with `\bigskip\noindent`", in which case the clear response is to adjust the preamble so that happens automatically.  Since that would be the point of a package/class, having `\noindent` there could make sense.  (But "a title preceding a description" could use a lot more details explaining OP's intent.)

Comment: @Teepeemm Agreed. And indeed, more clarity and fewer accounts would help a great deal. I happen to have read the earlier stuff the question alluded to, but the whole thing is very unclear, to be honest.